# Work problem - chain hanging on the ground

Tags: integration, applications

I am a bit tripped up on the following work problem --

A 30 ft long chain is hanging from one end on a hook, 25 feet above the ground; naturally, this means 5 feet of the hook are on the ground itself. The total weight of the chain is 120 lbs. How much work is required to life the other end of the chain to the same hook, so that both ends of the chain are 25 feet above the ground?

I have solved problems similar to this that didn't include the 5 trailing feet on the ground–but will this really affect the setup of the integral?

I set it up as follows :

$$\int_0^{30} 4x dx $$ ⇒

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain on the ground starts out with zero potential energy, so the upper limit should be $25$. This gives you the starting value. At the end, the chain is doubled, so you can consider it to be two $15$ foot chains hanging from the hook. Where is the bottom?

Comment: Okay, so I assume my limits will be come 0 to 30– not sure i follow you on the chain doubling notion? Why would i need to take this into account?

Comment: What is the range of heights of the chain after it is hung?  Those are the limits of your integral that time.

Comment: Okay, so... 5 to 30? and the 4xdx stays the same? Thanks!

Comment: No, both ends of the chain are attached to the hook.  Where is the middle?  Draw a picture.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed in reading the problem that both ends of the chain were attached the hook... Anyways - ( and i did draw a quiet nice picture )  So I believe that would make my limits become 0-25, since the other end of the chain has to go from 0 feet on the ground to 25 feet to the hook? Still 4xdx? If I only consider the second 15 feet of the chain actually moving, that would be 60lb/15 feet, making my force still equal to 4xdx ? Is this correct?

Comment: To compute the potential energy, you just integrate the height of each little bit of chain times its altitude.  The integral you gave in the question is fine for the starting potential energy.  Now you need the final potential energy.  Don't worry about how the chain moves, just see how much energy is there at the end.  The difference in potential energy is the work done.

Comment: Would something like 4x(30-x)dx be what I am aiming for to account for the difference in potential energy? 30 being the distance each little bit has to move minus the change in x?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35895/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-jimhacklebarth).